# Espresso test on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, junit4, android-espresso

I started test driven dev but an error came to me at the start.
I dont understand the exception:

```
E/TestRunner: androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'actionOnItemAtPosition performing ViewAction: single click on item at position: 0' on view 'with id: com.jakchang.idus:id/recyclerView'. at blabla~
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
    (is assignable from class: class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView and is displayed on the screen to the user)
    Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131230893, res-name=recyclerView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@1a52327, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}"
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:252)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:65)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:158)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call
```

and my code below

```
@JvmField
@Rule
var mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun recyclerTest(){
    onView(withId(R.id.homeIcon)).perform(click())
    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(0,click()))
}
```

when  activity started and only using

```
onView(withId(R.id.homeIcon)).perform(click())
```

seems to work but when the following line gets executed

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(0,click()))
```

the error appears.

layer-structue looks like this

```
constraint-layout
  -linear-layout
  --home_icon
 -scroll view
  --linear-layout
   ---recyclerview
   ---progressbar
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is the `RecyclerView` displayed on the screen to the user at that moment?

Comment: Your `RecyclerView` has no child views when you perform the action. Maybe your list is loaded asynchronously?

Comment: Yes RecyclerView  is loaded asynchronously So it displayed

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you might have to first scroll the `ScrollView` until the `RecyclerView` is shown to the user before executing the `actionOnItemAtPosition` instruction.

Try adding `onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo());` before that. The test will be:

```
@Test
fun recyclerTest(){
    onView(withId(R.id.homeIcon)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo(),
       RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(0,click()));
}
```

Comment: previous error is deleted but new error came to me.   that is             androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll to' on view 'with id: com.jakchang.idus:id/recyclerView' bla bla~  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Scrolling to view was attempted, but the view is not displayed....

Comment: Has your `ScrollView` some padding? If so, could you move it to the `LinearLayout` which is inside and try again?

Comment: I have no paading and margin in scrollview and added the scrollview in LinearLayout. but the result is same..

Comment: I tested this on recyclerview in one linear-layout with no others. it's working. but when I use it on some complicated layout, it's not working.